# Stack different column values into one column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, melt

I have the following dataframe -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    'Prior': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    'Current': ['a1', 'c', 'c1', 'e', 'f', 'f1', 'g1'],
    'Date': ['1/1/2019', '5/1/2019', '10/2/2019', '15/3/2019', '6/5/2019',
             '7/9/2019', '16/11/2019']
})
```

This is my desired output -

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    'Prior_Current': ['a', 'a1', 'b', 'c', 'c1', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f1', 'g',
                      'g1'],
    'Start_Date': ['', '1/1/2019', '', '5/1/2019', '10/2/2019', '', '15/3/2019',
                   '6/5/2019', '7/9/2019', '', '16/11/2019'],
    'End_Date': ['1/1/2019', '', '5/1/2019', '10/2/2019', '', '15/3/2019',
                 '6/5/2019', '7/9/2019', '', '16/11/2019', '']
})
```

I tried the following -

```
keys = ['Prior', 'Current']
df2 = (
    pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', value_vars=keys, value_name='Prior_Current')
        .merge(df[['ID', 'Date']], how='left', on='ID')
)
df2['Start_Date'] = np.where(df2['variable'] == 'Prior', df2['Date'], '')
df2['End_Date'] = np.where(df2['variable'] == 'Current', df2['Date'], '')
df2.sort_values(['ID'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

But this does not seem be working. Please help.

Comment: For Code formatting use `\`` not `'`

Comment: please help with the solution too

Answer (score 1):

#### you can use `stack` and `pivot_table`:

```
k = df.set_index(['ID', 'Date']).stack().reset_index()
df = k.pivot_table(index = ['ID',0], columns = 'level_2', values = 'Date', aggfunc = ''.join, fill_value= '').reset_index()
df.columns = ['ID', 'prior-current', 'start-date', 'end-date']
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
    ID prior-current  start-date    end-date
0    1             a                1/1/2019
1    1            a1    1/1/2019            
2    2             b                5/1/2019
3    2             c    5/1/2019   10/2/2019
4    2            c1   10/2/2019            
5    3             d               15/3/2019
6    3             e   15/3/2019    6/5/2019
7    3             f    6/5/2019    7/9/2019
8    3            f1    7/9/2019            
9    4             g              16/11/2019
10   4            g1  16/11/2019
```

#### Explaination:

After `stack` / `reset_index` df will look like this:

```
   ID        Date  level_2   0
0    1    1/1/2019    Prior   a
1    1    1/1/2019  Current  a1
2    2    5/1/2019    Prior   b
3    2    5/1/2019  Current   c
4    2   10/2/2019    Prior   c
5    2   10/2/2019  Current  c1
6    3   15/3/2019    Prior   d
7    3   15/3/2019  Current   e
8    3    6/5/2019    Prior   e
9    3    6/5/2019  Current   f
10   3    7/9/2019    Prior   f
11   3    7/9/2019  Current  f1
12   4  16/11/2019    Prior   g
13   4  16/11/2019  Current  g1
```

Now, we can use `ID` and `column 0` as index / `level_2` as column / `Date` column as value.

Finally, we need to rename the columns to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to build and attain the target df step by step. The first step is an extension of your code using `melt()` and `merge()`. The merge is done based on the columns 'Current' and 'Prior' to get the start and end date.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    'Prior': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    'Current': ['a1', 'c', 'c1', 'e', 'f', 'f1', 'g1'],
    'Date': ['1/1/2019', '5/1/2019', '10/2/2019', '15/3/2019', '6/5/2019',
             '7/9/2019', '16/11/2019']
})
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', value_vars=['Prior', 'Current'], value_name='Prior_Current').drop('variable',1).drop_duplicates().sort_values('ID')
df2 = df2.merge(df[['Current', 'Date']], how='left', left_on='Prior_Current', right_on='Current').drop('Current',1)
df2 = df2.merge(df[['Prior', 'Date']], how='left', left_on='Prior_Current', right_on='Prior').drop('Prior',1)
df2 = df2.fillna('').reset_index(drop=True)
df2.columns = ['ID', 'Prior_Current', 'Start_Date', 'End_Date']
```

Alternative way is to define a custom function to get date, then use `lambda` function:

```
def get_date(x, col):
    try:
        return df['Date'][df[col]==x].values[0]
    except:
        return ''

df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', value_vars=['Prior', 'Current'], value_name='Prior_Current').drop('variable',1).drop_duplicates().sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
df2['Start_Date'] = df2['Prior_Current'].apply(lambda x: get_date(x, 'Current'))
df2['End_Date'] = df2['Prior_Current'].apply(lambda x: get_date(x, 'Prior'))
```

Output

[image]